# When is a real-analytic function harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I recently learnt that every harmonic function occurs as the real part of a *complex* analytic function. We also know that every harmonic function is *real* analytic. So, when is a real-analytic function harmonic ?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? I suppose "$u$ is harmonic when $\Delta u =  0$" is not what you're after.

Comment: I want a criterion to say that a given power series with real co-efficients is harmonic. We know that every power series is not harmonic.I hope I'm not missing something fundamental here .

Answer (score 1):

When $-\Delta u=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_k^2}=0$

I believe an equivalent property is the mean integral property, I.e.:

$u(x)=\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dS(y)=\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^{n}}\int_{ B(x,r)}u(y)dy$, $\forall r\gt 0$.

Where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume on the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score -1):

A real valued function can never be analytic except a constant function.let it be a $~f(z)=x~$ so it have to satisfy CR equation. but here $~Ux=1~$ but $~Vy=0~$. So CR equation not satisfied  so not differentiable any where.so we can't talk about analytic but it is hormonic.

Comment: An analytic function is a function that has a convergent power series. The only complex-analytic function that is real valued is a constant function, but there are many real analytic functions that are not constant; e.g. $e^{-|x|^2}$.

Comment: Your function is not analytic.Reconfirm it please

Comment: It is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: but I'm talking in complex

Comment: The question specifically says "real-analytic", so complex analytic functions are not what the question is about.